# Traffic Light System Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am currently creating a **Car Parking and Driving Simulation** game but I'm having a problem making it. Currently what I successfully implemented

1. Park the Car
2. Game Over when the Car Crash into something
3. Traffic Light System

The problem is that if my car go forward when the traffic light is green and then suddenly it turns out to be red on the other traffic light it will trigger the next collider and I don't want that because it is a mistake right? . Please see the image below.

The **StopAndGoHandler GameObject** has the script called **StopAndGoHandler.cs**
[image]
this handles if the traffic light is green you can go,yellow prepare to stop but still you can go,red to fully stop. Now if the car go forward even if the traffic light is red then that comes the

**Violation GameObject** which has the script **TrafficViolation.cs**
[image]

Here's the **StopAndGoHandler.cs**

```
public GameObject tlc;
public Text[] Obey_Traffic_Rules;


private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){

    if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")){
        TrafficLightSignal();
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other){

    if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")){
        TrafficRulesInit();
    }
}

public void TrafficLightSignal(){
    var TLC = tlc.GetComponent<TrafficLightHandler>();  
    Debug.Log (TLC.Trafficlight.ToString());
    if (TLC.Trafficlight == TRAFFIC_LIGHT.GREEN) {
        TrafficRules(Obey_Traffic_Rules[0], true);
        TrafficRules(Obey_Traffic_Rules[1], false);
        TrafficRules(Obey_Traffic_Rules[2], false);
        TrafficRules(Obey_Traffic_Rules[3], false);
    } else if (TLC.Trafficlight == TRAFFIC_LIGHT.YELLOW) {
        TrafficRules (Obey_Traffic_Rules [1], true);
        TrafficRules(Obey_Traffic_Rules[2], false);
        TrafficRules(Obey_Traffic_Rules[3], false);
        TrafficRules(Obey_Traffic_Rules[0], false);
    } else if (TLC.Trafficlight == TRAFFIC_LIGHT.RED) {
        TrafficRules(Obey_Traffic_Rules[2], true);
        TrafficRules(Obey_Traffic_Rules[0], false);
        TrafficRules(Obey_Traffic_Rules[1], false);
        TrafficRules(Obey_Traffic_Rules[3], false);
    } else {
        // nothing
    }
}

public void TrafficRules(Text t, bool val){
        t.gameObject.SetActive (val);
}

public void TrafficRulesInit()
{
    TrafficRules(Obey_Traffic_Rules[0], false);
    TrafficRules(Obey_Traffic_Rules[1], false);
    TrafficRules(Obey_Traffic_Rules[2], false);
    TrafficRules(Obey_Traffic_Rules[3], false);
}
```

Here's my **TrafficViolation.cs** that inherets **StopAndGoHandler.cs**

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
    if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")){
        _TrafficViolation();
    }
}

private void _TrafficViolation(){
    var TLC = tlc.GetComponent<TrafficLightHandler>();
    if (TLC.Trafficlight == TRAFFIC_LIGHT.RED) {
        TrafficRules (Obey_Traffic_Rules [3], true);
        TrafficRules (Obey_Traffic_Rules [0], false);
        TrafficRules (Obey_Traffic_Rules [1], false);
        TrafficRules (Obey_Traffic_Rules [2], false);
    } else {
        TrafficRules (Obey_Traffic_Rules [0], true);
        TrafficRules (Obey_Traffic_Rules [1], false);
        TrafficRules (Obey_Traffic_Rules [2], false);
        TrafficRules (Obey_Traffic_Rules [3], false);
    }
}
```

By the way tlc is my TrafficLightSystem which just has an enum

```
public enum TRAFFIC_LIGHT
{
    GREEN,
    YELLOW,
    RED
};
```

my **TrafficLightHandler.cs** just changes the material of a sphere from red,green and yellow.

Someone please help me out if I'm doing this game correctly if not could you please guide me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that if my car go forward when the traffic light is
>   green and then suddenly it turns out to be red on the other traffic
>   light it will trigger the next collider and I don't want that because
>   it is a mistake right? .

What I understand for this text and from the image you added in the post is the car crosses the green traffic light without issues. But when it enters the crossing it triggers another traffic light collider, which belongs to a traffic light in red, causing the violation.

What I would do it to place the colliders which detect if a car cross a traffic light just under the traffic light itself, and not in the middle of the crossing. For example:

Assuming in each street, traffic can circulate in both directions, and since your traffic light are on the left, I assume car drive leftside (like in UK). I would place the traffic light OnTriggerEnter collider like this:

[image]

Comment: hmmmt that was a great idea. That was a big help

Comment: but what if he's going back sir should I make more colliders?

Comment: Well I am not sure exactly how realistic you want to make the game, but if the car triggers a collider of a traffic light in green and just after crosses a traffic light in red, that means he is driving in the opposite direction of the traffic, and that should be anyway a violation.

Comment: okay I'll mark this as my answer thanks that was a very big help for me . :)